# Edittext convert input value to float in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, focuslistener

I have one Edittext.My edittext inputType is  numberDecimal

```
 <EditText
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/u_widget_height"
                            android:id="@+id/transfer_maney"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                            android:hint="Amount"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/centerline"
                            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/centerline"
                            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/u_common_margin_left"
                            />
```

i want to change input value when  focus finished in my Editytext.i wrote some java code but i have NumberFormatException

```
  transfer_maney.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

            float inputFloatValue;
            if(!hasFocus)
            {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(contact_search.getText().toString())) {
                    inputFloatValue = 0F;

                } else {
                    inputFloatValue = Float.parseFloat(contact_search.getText().toString().trim());
                    Log.e("inputFloatValue",inputFloatValue+"");
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

simple i want to change input value  integer to float when i finish focus in my Edittext
if anyone knows solution please help me
thanks

Comment: what are you entering in the edittext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
float inputFloaValue= Float.parseFloat(transfer_maney.getText().toString().trim());
```

to:

```
float inputFloatValue;
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(transfer_maney.getText().toString())) {
  inputFloatValue = 0F;
} else {
  inputFloatValue = Float.parseFloat(transfer_maney.getText().toString().trim());
}
```

Comment: i updated my code but i still can't change input value when i finish focus  @Thomas R.

Comment: Do you still get an exception?

Comment: As mentioned in another answer, change `contact_search` to `transfer_maney`. Your are referencing the wrong view element. I updated my answer.

Comment: why `contact_search.getText().toString.trim()`?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when you dont enter any input in that feild it happens. you need to ensure that the length of string is greater than 0. I suggest you do a simple if check like

```
if(input!=null && input.length>0){
//parse to float
}else {
//throw error to user
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to convert the `transfer_maney` amount to `float` since that's what has the *focus listener* on. So, you need to use that `EditText` only when parsing the value. `contact_search` seems to be out of place there.

```
String amount = transfer_maney.getText().toString().trim();

float inputFloaValue = 0f;
if(amount.length() > 0)
{
    inputFloaValue = Float.parseFloat(amount);
    Log.d("inputFloatValue", String.valueOf(inputFloaValue));
}
```

Also, don't use `Log.e()` to log *debug* info. Use that strictly for exceptions.

Comment: I changed it  and working but if i input  17 i recived 17.0 and i want to recieve 17.00  and etc

Comment: A float will by default get displayed with only one 0 after the decimal. Use String.format() like Log.d("inputFloatValue", String.format("%.2f", inputFloaValue)); to get 17.00.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it pretty much right. Just a little change in your if statement

```
 if(transfer_maney.getText().toString().length()>0)
    if(transfer_maney.getText().toString().trim().length()>0)

    transfer_maney.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(!hasFocus)
            {
                if(transfer_maney.getText().toString().trim().length()>0)
                {
                    float inputFloaValue= Float.parseFloat(contact_search.getText().toString().trim());
                    Log.e("inputFloatValue",String.valueOf(inputFloaValue));

                }
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: I changed it  and working but if i input  17 i recived 17.0 and i want to recieve 17.00  and etc @Sukhvir

Comment: Use this:  float inputFloaValue= Float.parseFloat(contact_search.getText().toString().trim());
                   
           String userInput = String.format("%.2f",inputFloaValue);

Answer (score 0):

NumberFormatException causes here because you might be entering some thing which is not number or a float... restrict some special characters.